# Is there a way to specify all the GDCM libraries in CMakeList at once?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, gdcm

This may be a very basic question, but I am unable to find the answer.

I just installed GDCM library on my Windows 7 workstation and compiled it with CMake and later built the generated solution using VS2012 Express.
However, I'm unsure about which GDCM libraries to include in the CMakeLists and I was wondering if there was an easier way to specify all the libraries at once.(like VTK_LIBRARIES for VTK). I tried GDCM_LIBRARIES and that doesn't return a value, neither does GDCM.
Specifically, I am looking to replace:

> TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TestvtkGDCMImageReader vtkgdcm gdcmMSFF gdcmDSED gdcm2vtk)

with something more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, `GDCM_LIBRARIES` would be defined by the use file that you include after finding the GDCM package in CMake; however, it isn't currently set. You might just do it yourself by setting a variable with all of the GDCM library names.

For example, from looking at the libraries included in the 2.4.0 Windows binary distribution, I could do this in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set( GDCM_LIBRARIES
    gdcmDICT gdcmDSED gdcmIOD gdcmMEXD gdcmMSFF gdcmcharls gdcmexpat gdcmgetopt
    gdcmjpeg12 gdcmjpeg16 gdcmjpeg8 gdcmopenjpeg gdcmzlib
# since you built the vtk component, you might also include them here
    vtkgdcm gdcm2vtk
)

# then you can replace your line with this
target_link_libraries( TestvtkGDCMImageReader ${GDCM_LIBRARIES} )
```

Check out where the GDCM dlls you built are installed to see that you get all of the libraries.